# Python Flask import Error of module that isn´t being imported

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, import, itsdangerous

I have a flask app running in Google App Engine. Yesterday, I deployed a new version of my app where I only change the HTML style. It deployed as it was supposed to. Today, I realized that I didn't change the title for each corresponding HTML page, so I only changed the title tag in each HTML page. I deployed the app again and now I'm getting this strange error of an Import Error for a module that I have never even used. How can I fix this?

The error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous' (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/__init__.py)
```

**EDIT FEB 24, 2022:**

[image]

as you can see, the original folder to python3.7 has been replaced with python3.9

Is this normal in GAE?

Answer (score 6):

This [issue on Flask's GitHub](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4455) is related.

Either update to Flask>2, or if that's not possible pin ItsDangerous<2 and MarkupSafe<2.

To pin to lower versions in a requirements.txt file:

```
flask==1.1.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
markupsafe==1.1.1
```

Comment: thank you!  What had happend also was the that in the traceback, the directory says python3.7 which is the version I have always used. When I search the folder for python 3.7, Google App Engine last night had replaced it with python3.9....do you know if this always happens like this without warning?

Comment: Do you mean that the version of your App Engine service changed? It shouldn't as the runtime is [defined](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) on `runtime` configuration item from the `app.yaml` file.

Comment: yes sir it did....the app.yaml had not changed from its original 3.7 as i had left it.....but python version 3.7 was no longer in my cloud shell....there is only 2 folders...one that says Python2.7 and Python3.9....really weird :(

Comment: if this happens again I suggest to write the details it on another post on Stack or even report it on [Googles issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: Thank you!!   I was pulling my hair out about this error!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today. I was using `flask=1.1.2`, and when I updated the version to `flask==2.0.3`, the import issue was resolved.

Comment: I tried this and in fact worked for fixing the issue originally stated. But later in my code I had an operation with `.__dict__` property. Broke there because keys are not the same as in 1.1.2. For making things work without changing my code for the moment, stick to keep using `flask=1.1.2` and added these to requirements.txt: `itsdangerous==1.1.0` `markupsafe==1.1.1`.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by changes in Flask dependencies. Another question about this was [asked on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/1094062/321698).

You can either upgrade to Flask>2, or I had to downgrade to itsdangerous==2.0.1 if you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

the deprecation is performed with itsdangerous > 2.0.1.