# AppEngine Python 502 Bad Gateway - ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Last Friday I uploaded a new version of my application to App Engine. It was working before, but now I get a 502 Bad Gateway. If I go into the AppEngine console and direct traffic to an older version it works fine. So, I must have changed something, but what?

I pulled the logs and the following caught my attention:

*"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/json/**init**.py", line 15, in       from itsdangerous import json as _json  ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous' (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/itsdangerous/**init**.py)*

My requirements file is here:

```
Flask==1.1.4
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
requests==2.24.0
```

And my import sections are like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask import session, redirect, url_for, escape, request
from google.cloud import datastore
```

Any ideas where I can look?

Comment: Did you update Flask version during your update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Flask import Error of module that isn´t being imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173981/python-flask-import-error-of-module-that-isn%c2%b4t-being-imported)

Comment: Hi Gaefan, that was it. I upgraded Flask to 2.0.3 and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comment above, the issue was resolved by upgrading from Flask 1.1.2 to Flask 2.0.3